# An SE site for identifying an old postcard

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any place in the SE-universe to ask a question or seek for help in identifying an old (probably pre world war II) postcard, based on its front image (reproduction of Carl von. Bergen XIX century painting in this case) and printed information on the back? I am particularly interested in identifying the age of this post card or a year when it was published.

Or would such a question be off-topic everywhere (since identify-this-like questions aren't really liked anywhere)?

Comment: Identifying?, try tineye.com for very similar images and possibly where to buy. For less similar images.google.com works better. Once you can narrow your question to specify what you want to know about (you already know *what* the image is) then we can suggest [Travel.se], [photography.se], [history.se], etc.

Comment: It seems that I didn't provide enough detail. I am particularly interested in identifying the age of this post card or a year when it was published.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the specific framing of your question it may be on-topic on either [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) under the [identification](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) and [germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) tags, or on [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) under the [germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) tag ([Carl von Bergen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Bergen) was a German painter).

If you decide go for the latter, do carefully read through [What is “Genealogy,” “Family History,” and “Microhistory”?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/what-is-genealogy-family-history-and-microhistory) first. There was recently [a question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14868) asking for translation of a WW1 German postcard which belonged to the OP's great great grandfather and it received a fairly detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

General "identify the place or thing on this postcard" questions are likely also on-topic under the [identify-this] tag at [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this). Successful questions in that tag tend to be ones that are *identifiable* (major and minor landmarks count, random cafes and fire hydrants not so much) and *interesting from a travel perspective*. Since postcards generally fulfill both criteria (they tend to represent notable landmarks or vistas, and are generally recognizable to locals and frequent visitors), they are a good match for the site.

You specifically stated that the postcard has a print of a painting on it. A Travel.SE question could inquire as to where one might go today to view the original paining, and the site might also be open to identifying a postmark or stamp with a geographical location.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. When it comes to this particular postcard, Travel.se is a false shot, because this particular painting reproduction depicts a couple of children feeding ducks at the river, so neither landmark nor a view interesting from travel perspective. When it comes to "identify-this" tag at Travel.se in general then I also have certain doubts, because they seems to have some problems declaring themselves whether identify-this questions are or aren't on-topic on their site. So much for the clarification, which doesn't mean that your suggestion is wrong. Upvoting. Can't accept.